# How to filter react-chartjs-2

Tags: javascript, reactjs, chart.js, chartjs-2.6.0, react-chartjs

I am using react-chartjs-2 in my project, and I am creating a grouped stacked bar chart with it, to remove duplicate labels I have created a custom `generateLabels` function, but the problem with custom `generateLabels` function is that when I click on chart legend (ie. Cinema) it only updates the right side (taller) chart and the left side (smaller) chart doesn't update. I know that there is `onClick` function but I couldn't find how to use it:

```js
onClick: (e, legendItem) => {
        let i = legendItem.datasetIndex;
        let ci = chRef.current.chartInstance;
      }
```

```html
<Bar data={data} width={100} height={50} options={options} ref={chRef} />
```

Is there any solutions for this?
I want both charts (taller and smaller) to be updated.
I have highlighted the bar chart that updates in this image:
[image: t]

Here is my code

```js
import React, { useRef } from "react";
import { Bar } from "react-chartjs-2";

const mocked_data = {
  labels: ["Brand 1", "Brand 2", "Brand 3", "Brand 4", "Brand 5"],
  spend_per_channel: {
    spends: [
      {
        label: "Cinema",
        data: [56, 23, 55, 56, 57]
      },
      {
        label: "Retails",
        data: [22, 17, 32, 47, 62]
      },
      {
        label: "Fashion",
        data: [46, 73, 25, 76, 27]
      },
      {
        label: "Oil",
        data: [26, 40, 80, 50, 62]
      },
      {
        label: "Gas",
        data: [36, 13, 35, 46, 67]
      }
    ],
    sales: [
      {
        label: "Cinema",
        data: [156, 123, 155, 56, 157]
      },
      {
        label: "Retail",
        data: [122, 117, 132, 147, 162]
      },
      {
        label: "Fashion",
        data: [416, 173, 125, 176, 127]
      },
      {
        label: "Oil",
        data: [126, 135, 180, 100, 86]
      },
      {
        label: "Gas",
        data: [136, 113, 135, 146, 167]
      }
    ]
  }
};

const MyChart = () => {
  const chRef = useRef(null);

  const CHART_COLORS = [
    "#e35b2c",
    "#e77235",
    "#eb8a40",
    "#f0a04b",
    "#f5b858",
    "#f9cf63",
    "#fde76e",
    "#fced86",
    "#ffffb7",
    "#fefeeb"
  ];

  const spendsdata = mocked_data.spend_per_channel.spends.map(
    (spend, index) => {
      return {
        label: spend.label,
        backgroundColor: CHART_COLORS[index],
        data: spend.data,
        stack: 1
      };
    }
  );

  const salesdata = mocked_data.spend_per_channel.sales.map((sale, index) => {
    return {
      label: sale.label,
      backgroundColor: CHART_COLORS[index],
      data: sale.data,
      stack: 2
    };
  });

  const newdataset = [spendsdata, salesdata];
  const spnedperchanneldata = newdataset.flat();

  const data = {
    labels: ["Brand 1", "Brand 2", "Brand 3", "Brand 4", "Brand 5"],
    datasets: spnedperchanneldata
  };

  const options = {
    legend: {
      position: "bottom",
      labels: {
        generateLabels: function(chart) {
          return Chart.defaults.global.legend.labels.generateLabels
            .apply(this, [chart])
            .filter(function(item, i) {
              return i > 4;
            });
        },
        boxWidth: 10,
        usePointStyle: true
      },
      onClick: (e, legendItem) => {
        let i = legendItem.datasetIndex;
        let ci = chRef.current.chartInstance;
      }
    }
  };

  return (
    <>
      <Bar data={data} width={100} height={50} options={options} ref={chRef} />
    </>
  );
};

export default MyChart;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

you can check the live demo in this codesandbox [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/flamboyant-hypatia-tmy9k)

any help please?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use state variable to save data for charts and onclick of legend modifiy the state data and send new data to bar chart
Working code [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/dazzling-flower-211p2)

```
import React from "react";
import { Bar } from "react-chartjs-2";

const mocked_data = {
  labels: ["Brand 1", "Brand 2", "Brand 3", "Brand 4", "Brand 5"],
  spend_per_channel: {
    spends: [
      {
        label: "Cinema",
        data: [56, 23, 55, 56, 57]
      },
      {
        label: "Retails",
        data: [22, 17, 32, 47, 62]
      },
      {
        label: "Fashion",
        data: [46, 73, 25, 76, 27]
      },
      {
        label: "Oil",
        data: [26, 40, 80, 50, 62]
      },
      {
        label: "Gas",
        data: [36, 13, 35, 46, 67]
      }
    ],
    sales: [
      {
        label: "Cinema",
        data: [156, 123, 155, 56, 157]
      },
      {
        label: "Retail",
        data: [122, 117, 132, 147, 162]
      },
      {
        label: "Fashion",
        data: [416, 173, 125, 176, 127]
      },
      {
        label: "Oil",
        data: [126, 135, 180, 100, 86]
      },
      {
        label: "Gas",
        data: [136, 113, 135, 146, 167]
      }
    ]
  }
};

const MyChart = () => {
  const CHART_COLORS = [
    "#e35b2c",
    "#e77235",
    "#eb8a40",
    "#f0a04b",
    "#f5b858",
    "#f9cf63",
    "#fde76e",
    "#fced86",
    "#ffffb7",
    "#fefeeb"
  ];

  const spendsdata = mocked_data.spend_per_channel.spends.map(
    (spend, index) => {
      return {
        label: spend.label,
        backgroundColor: CHART_COLORS[index],
        data: spend.data,
        hidden: false,
        stack: 1
      };
    }
  );

  const salesdata = mocked_data.spend_per_channel.sales.map((sale, index) => {
    return {
      label: sale.label,
      backgroundColor: CHART_COLORS[index],
      data: sale.data,
      hidden: false,
      stack: 2
    };
  });

  const newdataset = [spendsdata, salesdata];
  const spnedperchanneldata = newdataset.flat();

  const [data, setData] = React.useState(spnedperchanneldata);
  const options = {
    legend: {
      position: "bottom",
      labels: {
        generateLabels: function(chart) {
          return Chart.defaults.global.legend.labels.generateLabels
            .apply(this, [chart])
            .filter(function(item, i) {
              return i > 4;
            });
        },
        boxWidth: 10,
        usePointStyle: true
      },
      onClick: (e, legend) => {
        onclick(legend);
      }
    }
  };

  const onclick = React.useCallback(
    legend => {
      let newData = data.map(item => {
        if (item.label === legend.text) item.hidden = !item.hidden;
        return item;
      });

      setData(newData);
    },
    [data, setData]
  );

  return (
    <>
      <Bar
        data={{
          labels: ["Brand 1", "Brand 2", "Brand 3", "Brand 4", "Brand 5"],
          datasets: data
        }}
        width={100}
        height={50}
        options={options}
      />
    </>
  );
};

export default MyChart;
```